# Running a script through another script does not understand PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, os.system

When I run and click the preview button, the os.system() runs and executes the test.py but does not recognize that I already have PIL. and gives out this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/adamd/Desktop/psychedelic_euphoria/test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
ImportError: No module named PIL
```

The one below is the script that will open the file test.py when I press preview.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import shutil
import os

location = '/Users/adamd/Desktop/psychedelic_euphoria'


def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    shutil.move(filename, location )

def OpenPreview():
    os.system('python /Users/adamd/Desktop/psychedelic_euphoria/test.py')




root = Tk()
root.title('Phychedelic Euphoria')
root.geometry("300x200")
bt_import = Button(root, text='Open', command=UploadAction)
bt_quit = Button(root, text='Quit',command=root.quit)
bt_preview = Button(root, text= 'preview',command=OpenPreview)




bt_import.pack(padx=20, pady=(20,0))
bt_quit.pack(padx=20, pady=(20,0))
bt_preview.pack(padx=20, pady=(20,0))


root.mainloop()
```

the one below is the test.py:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import cv2


view = Tk()

app = Frame(view, bg="white")
app.grid()

lmain = Label(app)
lmain.grid()


cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.avi')



def video_stream():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    cv2image = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGBA)
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2image)
    imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
    lmain.imgtk = imgtk
    lmain.configure(image=imgtk)
    lmain.after(1, video_stream) 

video_stream()
view.mainloop()
```

If I run test.py alone it works alright but once I run it through the first script from above it does not understand where the module PIL is.

Is there a way to solve this or do I have to alter the whole thing?
If it helps, I use macos.

Comment: How do you run the first program exactly?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I run it in the terminal using vs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a new script in VS code with:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Now use that path in your `os.system()`

Comment: where do I put that exactly? sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If it says VS code is using the Python interpreter at `/usr/local/bin/python3`, use `os.system('/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/adamd/Desktop/psychedelic_euphoria/test.py')`

Comment: Thank you soo much!!! I've spent the whole day trying to figure this out.

Comment: You're welcome - good luck with your project! Come back and ask some more if you get stuck - questions, and answers, are free on Stack Overflow.